# Stopping emacs deleting whitespaces

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I am using emacs for python on emacs24.4.1. Whenever I am saving python file, it is removing white space from whole file. I am looking for functionality of white space removal from my changes but not whole file. I tried setting (delete-whitespace nil) but it is not working

Any pointers?

Comment: Which Python mode are you using? Does this happen from `emacs -Q` as well?

Comment: As per duplicate Q&A, after disabling whatever custom config is responsible, use ws-trim.el or ws-butler.el in its place to get the behaviour you're looking for.